# Remove entire column with same strings (with header remains) using grep or awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, co

I have a file as below:

```
name1   name2   name3   name4    
AA  BB  BB  CC   
AA  AA  BB  CC   
AA  CC  BB  CC   
AA  DD  BB  DD   
AA  DD  BB  AA
```

column 1 and column 3 have the same string within itself. I wish to remove the entire column if the case is as described above but keep the header. So eventually the file will become something like this.

```
name2   name4   
BB  CC         
AA  CC   
CC  CC   
DD  DD   
DD  AA
```

Is there any way to do so using grep or awk? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your example, column 1 and 3 *don't* have the same strings at all, anywhere. I'm confused, and your question is confusing.

Comment: Clarification needed. If _every_ line of the file has column 1 and 3 equal (other than header of course), you want to remove column 1 and 3 from entire file?

Answer (score 1):

This is not completely optimal in terms of performance, but it does use `awk` and it does work for your sample input:

```
file=$1

header=$(head -1 "$file")
i=1
goodcols=""
for colname in $header; do
  count=$(awk "NR>1 {print \$$i}" "$file" | sort -u | wc -l)
  if [ $count -gt 1 ]; then
    if [ -z "$goodcols" ]; then
      goodcols="\$$i"
    else
      goodcols="$goodcols, \$$i"
    fi
  fi
  i=$((i+1))
done

awk "{print $goodcols}" "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to print the entire file if any of the column 1 and 3 values are different in any line, and only print columns 2 and 4 where *every* line has an identical value in columns 1 and 3, the following script will do it:

```
same=$(awk 'BEGIN{same=1}NR==1{next}$1!=$3{same=0;exit}{}END{print same}' qq.in)
if [[ $same -eq 1 ]] ; then
    awk '{print $2" "$4}' qq.in
else
    cat qq.in
fi
```

The first `awk` outputs `1` if all lines (other than the header of course) have an identical `column1/3` value. Otherwise it outputs `0`.

Then you simply use that to either filter the columns, or output the file as is.

If instead, you're wanting to strip columns 1 and 3 only if all the values in column 1 are identical and all the values in column 3 are identical (as per your test data), change the first line to:

```
allsame=$(awk 'BEGIN{allsame=1}NR==1{next}NR==2{val1=$1;val3=$3;next}$1!=val1||$3!=val3{allsame=0;exit}{}END{print allsame}' qq.in)
```

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX shell is simply an environment from which to call UNIX tools. The UNIX tool for general text manipulation is awk so just use it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (col=1; col<=NF; col++) {
        val[NR,col] = $col
        if ( (NR>1) && (!seen[col,$col]++) ) {
            cnt[col]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (row=1; row<=NR; row++) {
        ofs = ""
        for (col=1; col<=NF; col++) {
            if (cnt[col] != 1) {
                printf "%s%s", ofs, val[row,col]
                ofs = OFS
            }
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
name2 name4
BB CC
AA CC
CC CC
DD DD
DD AA
```